# go-guru on linux code in non-linux system

Tags: go, go-guru

We use docker and so the source code is for linux code. However, we develop on Macs, and as a result `go-guru-callers` fails to work when run locally.
It complains with the error below but the error is because that property is linux specific:

```
/Users/uri/Documents/connect/src/connect/job/native.go:104:4: unknown field Pdeathsig in struct literal
```

and the code:

```
    cmd.SysProcAttr = &syscall.SysProcAttr{
        Pdeathsig: syscall.SIGKILL,
    }
```

Any workarounds?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [build conditions](https://dave.cheney.net/2013/10/12/how-to-use-conditional-compilation-with-the-go-build-tool) to specify what code should be built on what OS and architecture, in order to separate out code that is platform-specific and avoid these kinds of compilation failures. See the [go build documentation here](https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/).